# Python Referencing a name of a class object in a function

Tags: python, function, class

I've never used classes before and I am trying to get a general understanding of how they work with the code example I have below. Im having issues referencing one of the names i define for a class. i just want the program to print out a list of the employee names and salaries stored in the list when the option 2 is entered but it gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scott Glenn\Misc\classes.py", line 31, in 
    employees[i].displayEmployee
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'displayEmployee'

```
class Employee:
    'Common base class for all employees'
    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayCount(self):
        print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary

def AddNewEmployee():
    NewEmployee = raw_input("What is the Employees name: ")
    employees.append(str(NewEmployee))
    NewEmployeeSalary = raw_input("What is the Employees salary: ")
    NewEmployee = Employee(NewEmployee, NewEmployeeSalary)
    return employees
#=============================================================================
employees=[]
while(1):
    print'Welcome to the Employee Database!'
    option = raw_input('Please select 1 to add new employee or 2 to      display all current employees: ')
    if option=='1':
        employees.append(AddNewEmployee())
    if option=='2':
        for i in range(0,len(employees)):
            employees[i].displayEmployee
```

Comment: employees is appending itself - you return the list employees as output from AddNewEmployee

Comment: You are just appending employees with an input string

Comment: You need to reconsider what you're doing with `Employee` objects, how you create them, and where you store them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AddNewEmployee` function is wrong. It's returning a `list` of a single `string` when you want to be returning a single object of your custom type `Employee`.

It should be more like this:

```
def AddNewEmployee():

    #string variable to hold name
    NewEmployeeName = raw_input("What is the Employees name: ")

    #why make a list? you are appending the result of this function to that list
    #employees.append(str(NewEmployee))
    #plus this is adding the employee before he's even been created

    NewEmployeeSalary = raw_input("What is the Employees salary: ")

    #construct using name string and salary string
    NewEmployee = Employee(NewEmployeeName, NewEmployeeSalary) 

    return NewEmployee #return Employee object (to be appended later)
```

Additionally, you are trying to access `displayEmployee()` as a *field* of your class, instead of as a *method*. Fields don't have parenthesis and methods do (so they can take parameters, though in this case the parenthesis are empty as no parameters are passed).

Finally, note that `raw_input` returns a `string` so you should cast to `float` if that is what you wish your `NewEmployeeSalary` to be. (Right now it's a `string`.)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code below.  The main issue that I saw that you had was that you were using 'employees' as a global and appending to it twice.  I moved it out of the AddNewEmployee() function and had that return the new employee which is then appended to 'employees'

Also you weren't calling '.displayEmployees' 
Notice the the parentheses that I added to the end.

I hope this helps!

```py
class Employee(object):
    'Common base class for all employees'
    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayCount(self):
        print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print "Name : ", self.name, ", Salary: ", self.salary


def AddNewEmployee():
    NewEmployee = raw_input("What is the Employees name: ")
    NewEmployeeSalary = raw_input("What is the Employees salary: ")
    NewEmployee = Employee(NewEmployee, NewEmployeeSalary)
    return NewEmployee


# =============================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":

    employees = []
    while True:
        print'Welcome to the Employee Database!'
        option = raw_input(
            'Please select 1 to add new employee or 2 to display all current employees: ')
        if option == '1':
            employees.append(AddNewEmployee())
        if option == '2':
            for i in range(0, len(employees)):
                employees[i].displayEmployee()
```